# Removing a value from seed file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake

I have a seed file in my application : `friends_seed_data.rb`. It consists of these values : `["NEW", "OLD", "DELETED"]`. I ran `rake db:seed` a while ago and I now have these three conditions in my db.

Now, I don't need the condition `OLD` anymore. How should I remove this condition from my seed file. I have converted all my data consisting of `OLD` condition to `NEW` condition in my db. My seed file looks like :

```
friends_conditions = ["NEW", "OLD", "DELETED"]
friends_conditions.each do |f|
  s = Friends::Condition.find_or_initialize_by_name(name: f)
  if s.new_record?
    s.save!
  else
    #Do nothing
  end
end
```

Running `rake db:seed` after deleting `OLD` does nothing. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seed file is usually used only to populate the database from a blank state for the first time. The seed file - unless it is deleting entire tables and recreating them - can be ignored after the first run.

Removing `OLD` status has to be done in the database; not on the seed file.

> I have converted all my data consisting of OLD condition to NEW
>   condition in my db

From this, I am assuming that you have converted all the instances of `OLD` to `NEW` in your database. So there is nothing else to do. Ignore the seed file.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Thanks.